# What's the difference between using Cookieless = "True" and Cookieless = "UseUri"?

Tags: asp.net, session-cookies

I know both `HttpCookieMode` enumerated values in Cookieless attribute cookieless session, which will manage session by inserting session id in the URL. But what's the difference between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `UseUri` , cookies are never used despite the capabilities of the browsers or devices.The `SessionID` is passed along with the `url`.